# mapping cylinder contractible iff $H_n(f):H_n(X)\to H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

The mapping cylinder will be defined as $Z_f=X\times[0,1]\coprod Y/\sim$, where $\sim$  is defined by $(x,1)\sim f(x)$.

Let $f:X\to Y$ a continuous map between topological spaces and the map $i:X\hookrightarrow Z_f$ identifies $X$ with $X\times \{0\}\subset Z_f$ is the inlusion. $R$ is a ring. I want to know

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0\; H_n(f;R):H_n(X;R)\to H_n(Y;R)$ is an isomorphism iff $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0 \;H_n(Z_f,X)=0$

Here we consider the singular homology. I don't know how to prove this, sorry. Maybe for the direction $\Leftarrow$ we can consider a map of pairs get a long exact sequence. One of the first thoughts I have that the chain complex $(C_n(Z_f,X),d_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is contractible (identity is chain homotopic to the zero map). But I don't know why it could be useful.

How to prove the statement? Any help is appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Consider $X \rightarrow Z_f \rightarrow (Z_f, X)$. Hint: $Z_f \simeq Y$.

Comment: thank you. ok, the map $f:X\to Y$ can be written as composition $X \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} Z_f \stackrel{j}{\rightarrow} Y$, where $i$ is the inclusion as a subset,$j$ is an homotopy equivalence. You claim that $Z_f $ is homotopy equivalent to Y? then $H_n(Z_f;R)\cong H_n(Y;R)$ .. but i still dont see how to prove the <=>, sorry:/

Comment: The homotopy equivalence is the inclusion $Y \rightarrow Z_f$, and $X \rightarrow Z_f$ is the inclusion from $X$ to $Z_f$. Show: under this homotopy equivalence of $Y$ and $Z_f$, the inclusion from $X$ to $Z_f$ is homotopy equivalent to the map from $X$ to $Y$. (This is in fact the motivation for defining a mapping cylinder. The idea is to "slide down the $[0,1]$ coordinate.")

Comment: And then use the long exact sequence on homology from $X \rightarrow Z_f \rightarrow (Z_f,X)$.

Comment: ok, thank you! Now maybe i see how to do it with your explanation, i will try it. Thanks!